# How to handle checkboxes in a PySide table?

Tags: python, pyside

I have a `QtGui.QTableWidget` with four columns, the last one should show a checkbox. The table is created like this:

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 4, self)
self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Description", "Status"])
self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
self.table.cellChanged.connect(self._cellChanged)
```

The last column of each table row is created like this:

```
cb = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("deactive")
cb.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
self.table.setItem(idx, 3, cb)
```

Now when the user clicks the checkbox in a table row, I want to change the text for the checkbox accordingly. So I hooked to the `cellChanged` signal, as shown above. For that even I do the following:

```
def _cellChanged(self, row, column):
    if column == 3:
        print self.table.itemAt(row, column).checkState()
        text = "active" if self.table.itemAt(row, column).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked else "deactive"
        self.table.itemAt(row, column).setText(text)
```

However, that does not work. Regardless of whether the user checks or unchecks the checkbox, the `checkState()` method always returns `Unchecked`.

Any ideas what I am missing or missunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records, I found the solution. I need to use `self.table.item()` instead of `self.table.itemAt()`.